# Client Side Authentication against Facebook

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, authentication, controller, facebook-access-token

We have a spring web app with spring mvc controllers. It's supposed to connect to our facebook app to get an authentication token to be used for further access. The communication with our App seems to work. When I hit the link

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=something&redirect_uri=http://our.domaine.register/postback?user_id=12345&scope=manage_pages&response_type=code">connect</a>
```

it will redirect me to facebook, I'll enter my credentials and get redirected back to

```
our.domaine.register/postback?user_id=12345&code=SoMEcOde
```

This again is one of our Spring MVC controllers but that doesn't really matter because

**the problem is, the code returned by facebook is a malformed accessToken**,

meaning if I try to use it to access a protected resource it won't work. Replacing the same call with an access token retrieved via graph API explorer it works fine.

The returned code has a peculiar format with '-', '_' and '=' characters in it which a normal access token never has.

So I'm assuming there has to be some kind of conversion to be done?! Or is it some kind of formating problem?

Returned token:

`AQBoXkcR5zRUiuHoO_lLdQfnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxoPPvZQTeybT9ebsI2SD1Xk`

**Is code the same as accessToken?**

The official documentation mostly just talks about using the anchor hash (REDIRECT_URL/#access_token=...) and accessing the access_token via javascript, though I have no idea why I would want to do that it's not natural and not testable...

Has anyone used the code argument to map it as a request parameter so that it can be accessed in a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The code they are returning to you is an OAuth authorization code, no access token. You have to exchange that one for an access token with another call. See point 4 in Facebook's [documentation for server-side authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)</strike>

**UPDATE:**
(Sorry, missed the headline, where you say "Client Side Authentication" ;))

Use `response_type=token` instead of `response_type=code`, so you directly get an access token in return and not an OAuth authorization code. See the section *Client-side authentication without the JS SDK* on Facebook's [documentation for client-side authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/).

**UPDATE:**

As you are trying to develop a web application, the [server-side authentication flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) is the correct one to use. That means exchanging the authorization code (the one you get after redirecting the user) for an access token with another call.

So if I understand it correct now, your problem is how you get the access token out of the response you receive. Check [this example](http://faheemsohail.com/2012/03/integrating-java-spring-mvc-and-facebook-part-1/) for how to do such things using Spring. For your case this would be something like to get the authorization code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postback", params = "code", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
private void accessCode(@RequestParam("code") String code,
                            HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        //Now the variable 'code' holds the authorization code
}
```

Comment: Hey! Your first answer was actually what I am looking for, I think.. Please check my comment at WareNinjas reply. I'll try the exchange thing and if that's to complicated I guess I'll have to use javascript for the client side flow..

Comment: Working now. I take the code and then make a server side call to facebook to get the token. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2):

looks like your response_type is asking for code, that's why no token returned.

plz check the last section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

example for the right call;

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
   &response_type=token
```

and when login success, the redirect ur contains access_token and expires_in params appended.
you can decode the url params to get what you need.
here is sample function for [Android OAuth example](https://github.com/wareninja/generic-oauth2-login-for-android) (easy to adapt for java):

```
public static Bundle decodeUrl(String s) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        if (s != null) {
            String array[] = s.split("&");
            for (String parameter : array) {
                String v[] = parameter.split("=");
                // YG: in case param has no value
                if (v.length==2){
                    params.putString(URLDecoder.decode(v[0]),
                                 URLDecoder.decode(v[1]));
                }
                else {
                    params.putString(URLDecoder.decode(v[0])," ");
                }
            }
        }
        return params;
    }

    /**
     * Parse a URL query and fragment parameters into a key-value bundle.
     * 
     * @param url the URL to parse
     * @return a dictionary bundle of keys and values
     */
    public static Bundle parseUrl(String url) {

        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            Bundle b = decodeUrl(u.getQuery());
            b.putAll(decodeUrl(u.getRef()));
            return b;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "parseUrl ex ->" + e.toString());
            return new Bundle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that if I request it with type token I get it directly. But I'm not sure how to extract the token from the anchor hash #access_token in my controller. As far as I'm aware, I'd need to use Javascript to do that and I really want to avoid that. So I figured, since code was returned as a request parameter I'd go with that... I found that I should then use server side authentication to exchange the code for a token..

Comment: you can parse the login_success response url, it contains access_token and expires_in as params. I'll attach example code to my prev answer